# How to add a threshold in softmax scores

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, classification, multilabel-classification

When doing multi-classcification usually I got a softmax score and predictoins with below,

```
softmax_scores = tf.nn.softmax(logits=self.scores, dim=-1)
prediction=tf.argmax(self.scores, 1, name="predictions")
```

If the softmax_socres I got is `[0.5,0.2,0.3]`.The prediction is `[0]`.
Now I want to add thresholds `0.6` to softmax_socres.Which means the prediction  expected here is `[4]`  which means others.
I did as below

```
threshold=0.6
self.predictions = tf.argmax(self.scores, 1, name="predictions")
x = tf.constant([num_classes], shape=self.predictions.shape, dtype=tf.int64)
self.predictions1 =tf.where(tf.reduce_max(tf.nn.softmax(logits=self.scores, dim=-1),1)>=threshold,self.predictions,x)
```

And got:

```
File "E:\ai\wide-and-shallow cnn\text_cnn.py", line 102, in __init__
    x = tf.constant([num_classes], shape=self.predictions.shape, dtype=tf.int64)
  File "E:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 214, in constant
    value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
  File "E:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py", line 430, in make_tensor_proto
    if shape is not None and np.prod(shape, dtype=np.int64) == 0:
  File "E:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 2566, in prod
    out=out, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 35, in _prod
    return umr_prod(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
TypeError: __int__ returned non-int (type NoneType)
```

It worked in this demo.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
a=tf.constant(np.arange(6),shape=(3,2))
b=tf.reduce_max(a,1)
#c=tf.to_int32(a>3)
c=tf.argmax(a,1)
d=b>=3
f=tf.constant([5],shape=c.shape,dtype=tf.int64)
e=tf.where(d,c,f)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(a.eval(),b.eval(),c.eval(),d.eval(),f.eval(),e.eval())
```

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13082 - see if ppwwyyxx's answer helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about doing it this way, with the use of `tf.where`

```
threshold = 0.6

softmax_scores = tf.nn.softmax(logits=self.scores, dim=-1)

other_class_idx = tf.cast(tf.shape(softmax_scores)[0] + 1, tf.int64)
other_class_idx = tf.tile( \
    tf.expand_dims(other_class_idx, 0), \
    [tf.shape(softmax_scores)[0]] \
)

is_other = tf.reduce_max(tf.cast(softmax_scores > threshold, tf.int8), axis=1)

predictions = tf.where( \
                 is_other>0, \
                 tf.argmax(softmax_scores, 1), \
                 other_class_idx \
              ) # 4
```

Comment: The demo worked, but not working in the project. ValueError: Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 2 for 'output/cond/Switch' (op: 'Switch') with input shapes: [?,13], [?,13].

Comment: I assume the `softmax_scores` tensor is of shape [?, num_classes] then. I edited the answer to reflect that. Note that we are now using `tf.where` instead of `tf.cond`

Comment: Thank you! It works only without lambda in tf.where.